# Does the website not like Java?

Tags: java, url

I'm trying to open my university's website to read their menu. I've written a version that reads the menu given the link directly to the menu link, but I want to pull it back a little so I can read the menu from the website and not the direct link (in case the link ever changes).

Here is the URL I am opening: 
https://nccudining.sodexomyway.com/dining-choices/index.html

Whenever I open the link to the website, this is the output that I get:

```
302
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://m-nccudining.sodexomyway.com/dining-choices/index.html">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

The URL it outputs is the mobile version of the website, but when I try to use that URL, it outputs nothing.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        URL url = null;

        try
        {
            url = new URL("https://nccudining.sodexomyway.com/dining-choices/index.html");
            HttpURLConnection test = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            test.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            test.connect(); 
            System.out.println(test.getResponseCode());
        } catch ( MalformedURLException e1 )
        {
            System.out.println("URL cannot be opened.");
            return;
        }

        BufferedReader in = null;
        try
        {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            System.out.println("Error");            
        }
        String inputLine;

        try
        {
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }       
    }
}
```

I apologize for all the try/catch loops. I don't want to just throw an IOException from the main from the get-go because I've heard that's bad practice. Anyway, this code just opens the URL, sets up a connection so I can make sure the URL actually exists, and try to read the HTML of it. It works on any other site I've tried it on, including google.

My question is why will my code not read the correct source code of the website? Is it something wrong with my code (I figured adding in the HttpsURLConnection and allowing redirects would work) or is it just the website, and is there anything I can do to bypass that aside from just opening the weekly menu's page?

**Solution found!** Thanks to @ShayHaned for the fixes. I added the following lines to the HttpURLConnection so I got a 200 response code rather than a 302:

```
        test = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        test.setRequestMethod("GET");
        test.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        test.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
```

Then I changed the InputStream from opening the stream from the URL to getting the input stream from the HttpURLConnection, as shown:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(test.getInputStream()));
```

That gave me the HTML I was looking for.

Comment: What is the response code? If it isn't 301 or similar, the problem is at the server end: they aren't issuing a redirect, so Java isn't following one.

Comment: @EJP That's what's in his first code block...

Comment: It reads the HTML of the webpage. Right now, it doesn't do anything with what it reads since I just wanted to get this fixed.

Comment: @JimGarrison `setInstanceFollowRedirects()` does exactly that, and it is also the default.

Comment: The response code for the HttpURLConnection returns 302.

Comment: The website probably inspects the user-agent header (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent), and somehow decides that the one sent by Java (or its absence, if Java doesn't send any) should make it redirect to the mobile web site. Just send the user-agent header of a well-known desktop web browser.

Comment: If you consider throwing `IOException` from the main method to be bad practice, then what you are doing is even worse... have fun finding out what is wrong when you just see "Error". In your case, just throw it up or else at least call `printStackTrace()` on the exception.

Comment: @NickL The "Error"s are just here temporarily. In my actual program, I have more accurate exceptions. I just threw this together real quick as I was testing it. And I was debugging it so I could check which error was thrown.

Comment: Are you still getting exceptions after trying the solution that was posted? Please try the code posted in answer and further clarifications will be made if the answer is not helping, because I got the complete html page after applying the fix in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing the appropriate headers for http communication to work safely and securely. You can add a few Headers to make sure that you get the desired response

```
    HttpURLConnection test = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    test.addRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" );
    test.addRequestProperty( "Accept" , "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,image/png, image/svg+xml,;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    test.addRequestProperty( "Accept-Charset" , "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
    test.addRequestProperty( "Accept-Language" , "en-US,en;q=0.8" );
    test.addRequestProperty( "Connection" , "close" );
    test.setRequestMethod("GET");
        

    test.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    test.connect();

    // Nopes DONT TRY THIS
    //in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( test.getInputStream() ) );      
    String htmlContent = "";
    for( String inputLine = ""; ( inputLine = in.readLine() ) != null; )
        htmlContent += inputLine;
    System.out.println( htmlContent );
```

Instead of **in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream() ) );** , please try **in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(test.getInputStream() ) );** , because it sounds pretty logical to **open your InputStream from the actual HttpURLConnection object** .

If you really want to understand the http header part try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields for a detailed description of http headers and usage

Comment: Why? What is the purpose of `Connection: close` here? and `Accept`? and `Accept-Charset`? and `Accept-Language`. A mere magic potion is not sufficient. You have to *explain.*

Comment: **A mere magic potion is not sufficient** , completely agreed, but atleast he gets to be sure that the code is running and gives the accurate result?? **You have to explain** , I certainly would, once he runs the code and comes back for explanation?? Because what just got down-rated was actually tested for accuracy before I even thought of uploading it as an answer

Comment: @ShayHaned I added the code, as now shown in the question, and it still didn't give me the full page.

Comment: I am not sure about the complete page but if **I'm trying to open my university's website to read their menu** is the case, then after applying the solution, I get the html text document with the complete menu thing that you mentioned, but since I can't review the html page you are getting, then we are certainly facing a deadlock then

Comment: Are you using the link I've posted in my question or the link specifically for the menu? I can read the one for the menu, it's the link that contains the link to the menus that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: I tested https://nccudining.sodexomyway.com/dining-choices/index.html , and I also retrieved the html page for this link. I am not sure how you are getting a blank html text its just not possible because I did get a complete html page for the link specified

Comment: and would you please replace **in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));** with **Reader reader =  new InputStreamReader( test.getInputStream() );** and then perform the reading. Please do let me know if that doesn't help too. Because the code is running perfectly on my side